# Offer (with priceSpecification) nested within Product throws Warning

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Nesting an Offer that has a priceSpecification inside a Product throws up an *Incomplete microdata* warning in Google Rich Snippets testing tool.

This

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">1984 Vintage Selection Cabernet Sauvignon</h1>
    <p itemprop="description">Cabernet Sauvignon.</p>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <p itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/priceSpecification">Prices start at 
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />£<span itemprop="price">0.71</span> (per bottle)</p>
        <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="2013-09-01" />
    </div>
</div>
```

throws the following warning in google rich snippets testing tool:
*Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.*

If I move Offer outside Product:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">1984 Vintage Selection Cabernet Sauvignon</h1>
    <p itemprop="description">Cabernet Sauvignon.</p>
</div>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <p itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/priceSpecification">Prices start at 
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />£<span itemprop="price">0.71</span> (per bottle)</p>
    <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="2013-09-01" />
</div>
```

then the warning is no longer thrown up, but this doesn't appear to make sense, as the Offer is not linked to the Product it's applicable to.

All the examples at schema.org nest Offer within Product, however, none of them use priceSpecification. I could only find one blog post where Offer is not nested within Product: http://seolobster.de/richsnippets-schema-org-products-update. This does not fill me with confidence to use in a live environment.

Which is correct? Especially if you throw in more than one Offer?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and I just figured it out though painstaking trial-and-error: The problem is that, even though *price* is part of the *priceSpecification* schema, it *still* needs to be defined outside the *priceSpecification* metatag in the regular *offer*, too!

I needed *priceSpecification* because we show prices including and excluding VAT, and now I have no frickin' idea on how to implement this! If I HAVE to define the price in *offer*, how do I tell it it's with or without VAT? *valueAddedTaxIncluded* is not part of the *offer* schema! An empty div just including *valueAddedTaxIncluded=true*? Okay, so how do I implement the other price without the VAT then? That would define the price twice in the offer, and that's not possible!

Also, why is schema.org and getschema.org so damn effing useless when it comes to samplecode and how to properly implement any given schema? If you want people to adopt some fancy new technology - TELL THEM HOW TO DO IT!!

Comment: I'm running into this same problem. We use multiple price breaks e.g. $1.00 for 1-2 units, $0.94 for 2-4, and so on. I naturally figured I would use multiple priceSpecification elements for each offer, only to find Google's validation tool throws an error. I also do not know what to put in the "price" field on the offer, other than the first price break? According to schema.org for offer price: " or of a price component when attached to PriceSpecification and its subtypes." I don't understand how to take this when multiple priceSpecification elements are allowed by the schema. It is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example I don't think you need to use a separate priceSpecification property. Instead you can directly add the price and priceCurrency property to the Offer like the example below.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">1984 Vintage Selection Cabernet Sauvignon</h1>
  <p itemprop="description">Cabernet Sauvignon.</p>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    Prices start at <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />£
    <span itemprop="price">0.71</span> (per bottle)
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed. I clearly stripped down my code example too much - the reason I use priceSpecification is so that I can use eligibleQuantity, eligibleTransactionVolume, price ranges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, the offer also needs the price-tag. One solution that the tag-tester allows is adding the data as a meta-tag like this:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="79" />
```

I'm not sure if google will parse and show this however.